# What is :format in rails rake routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What does the format below stand for? I know it's not necessary but what is it referring to?

```
articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
```

Answer (score 0):

That stands for the format that will be rendered(html, json, xml, ...).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data